# Migrate database without alembic_version table in python flask

Tags: database, flask-migrate

I like to migrate my database but I don't want `alembic_version` table in my database. It is possible without this `alembic_version` table. Is there any other solution or it is possible or not.

Comment: No idea if there is another migration framework out there, but it is certainly not possible with Flask-Migrate and Alembic.

Comment: I have searched alot but i also not get anything, I think it is not possible.

Comment: Do you have any idea that how to generate db migrate file outside the docker.

Comment: All the examples that I show in my tutorials generate migrations w/o Docker. I don't understand what you are asking, it's hard to do it inside a container, outside is easy.